# Get Server Callback about Payment Status when using Checkout Button with Non-Business Account

Tags: paypal

I frequently use the Paypal Express Checkout Button to collect money from friends, using the HTML form shown below.

Is it possible to tell PayPal to call a specific URL on my server indicating whether the payment was processed? I have implemented PayPal Express several times using a PayPal Business Account. However, my private account is not a business account, so I cannot use the API.
I have also read about Instant Update API and tried getting it to work, but it's not called for some reason.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="MY_PAYPAL_EMAIL">
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="DE">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="...">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="...">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
  <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="0.000">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0.00">

  <!-- Instant Update API -->
  <input type="hidden" name="callback_url" value="http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3000/paypal" />
  <input type="hidden" name="callback_timeout" value="3" />
  <input type="hidden" name="callback_version" value="61"/>

  <input type="hidden" name="fallback_shipping_option_name_0" value="Option 1">
  <input type="hidden" name="fallback_shipping_option_amount_0" value="0">
  <input type="hidden" name="fallback_shipping_option_is_default_0" value="1">

  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
    <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/i/logo/rebrand/ppcom.svg"/></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use IPN also with the checkout button. Use the following to get an IPN update:

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://XX.XX.XX.XX/YOUR_URL" />
```